# Indentation problem with kernel function in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, jenkins, visual-studio-code

I 'm currently using Jenkins for checking coding rules, and i develop on visual studio code. I never had problem since this one.

When I type the following in Visual Studio Code:

```
list_for_each_safe(position, tmp, &drv_dev->list_master) {
    //do something
}
```

But when I save the file with Visual Studio Code, it re-formats the code to:

```
list_for_each_safe (position, tmp, &drv_dev->list_master) {
    //do something
}
```

Notice the space after the `list_for_each_safe` name. This space makes my Jenkins pipieline fail.

So currently I have to open my file with Sublime Text to modify it before pushing.

Do you know any option to make Visual Studio Code avoid auto-formatting the code at a specific line?

Comment: VSC does this not out of the box, so you have an extension doing it. Disable them one by one or all and find out which one is the culprit and then look at the settings to find what you need to disable. Looks something for a prettier tool setting

Comment: THe only one i have is the C/C++ extensions.So i think this is the one causing me trouble, the fact is that i really like the autoindent function, just is this particular case i want to avoid it. But i will search in the extensions, thank you.

Comment: How is this related to `jenkins` or `kernel`? Please only add relevant tags to your question.

Comment: jenkins and kernel because i check my code through a jenkins pipeline that use kernel indentation style ;)

Comment: Well, you are using a mouse and electricity as well. ;) But the question is solely about code formatting in VS-Code

Comment: Yeah next time i will add the "atom" tag, so I'm sure to be global ;p.

Comment: https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/201970/ i find this kernel patch, its suppose to be fix since 2010 from what i see